# Deprecation notices building using GTKMM with C++11

Tags: c++11, compiler-warnings, gtkmm

I'm trying to use GTKMM with a project which makes use of C++11 features.
The problem is that apparently  C++11 deprecated some parts of the language, which GTKMM seems to be using.

Is there any way to get rid of those messages while keeping the useful compiler warnings for my code?

The compiler is GCC 5.2 on Linux. These are the notices I'm talking about:

```
In file included from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/wrap.h:23:0,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/containerhandle_shared.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/arrayhandle.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h:91,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:87,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/objectbase.h:215:13: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 static std::auto_ptr<Threads::Mutex> extra_object_base_data_mutex;
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5.2.0/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/objectbase.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/wrap.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/containerhandle_shared.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/arrayhandle.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h:91,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:87,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:49:28: note: declared here template<typename> class auto_ptr;
```

In case its something wrong with the compiler parameters, here's the CMakeLists ( was reused from an OpenCV project, please tell in case there is something wrong in the file):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
list( APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs -libs")

project( interface )
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM REQUIRED gtkmm-3.0)
include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTKMM_CFLAGS_OTHER})
add_executable( interface test.cpp )
target_link_libraries(interface ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Try adding the `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` flag to your command line. The warning message tells you the warning class that generates the message, so you can turn it off specifically.

Comment: That worked. What will happen whenver those features get removed from the language? Simply an error telling that feature xyz isn't found?

Comment: Yes, you'll get an error saying something like `no template auto_ptr found in namespace std`. `auto_ptr` will finally be removed from the language in the still-pending C++17 standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a dirty hack (because probably the usage of `auto_ptr` inside GTKMM is questionable so you want to report a bug to GTKMM); you might use some [diagnostic pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) and replace 
 `#include <gtkmm.h>` with

```
//untested code
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
#include <gtkmm.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning  "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
```

But `auto_ptr` is indeed deprecated in C++11 and I am not sure it mixes well with your C++11 standard library.
(Perhaps using [Qt5](http://qt.io/) instead of *GtkMM* might be reasonable, since GtkMM might not be maintained for long, however it seems to [know](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/gtkmm-tutorial.html#chapter-refptr) the issue; otherwise hope and perhaps contribute to improving GtkMM).

You probably should also use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) in your tests

Comment: So, that will ignore the deprecation notices from that library, and ONLY from that library restoring them after it is included?

Comment: Congrats for the 100k :)

Comment: In principle yes. I am not sure of what will happen (and when) for template instantiation

Comment: It seems to be working just fine. Also serves as a comment to tell that something is not perfect there :)

Comment: I tried to replace warnings with warning but for some reason the edit was refused. It works fine after that. Also I prefer GTK over QT and have the interface already done, so GTKMM is sort of a must here. The alternative would be to mix PyGobject with C++, and I don't know how. Even less when I somehow(still to find out) have to inject C++ structures from OpenCV into the interface.

Comment: "GtkMM might not be maintained for long" - Is there any basis to this, or is it just FUD? `gtkmm` looks _very_ well-maintained and has had the same maintainer for well over a decade AFAIK. I'm not at all worried about my use of it and have no interest in migrating to Qt5. (I might learn it later as an academic exercise.) A lot of arguments in favour of Qt seem to stem from FUD about GTK+, often from a false equation of GTK+ to GNOME. And yet GTK+/mm let me do things that Qt just won't, at least without reinventing the wheel. I'm sure the converse is true for other developers, but let's be fair

Answer (score 4):

We fixed this in glibmm fairly recently:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748630#c11

So the best way to fix it for your build is to update your glibmm and gtkmm versions, when you can.

Comment: I'm using the most recent version in the Arch repos, so probably no distro has that fix yet (maybe gentoo, no idea).
GTK 3.18 will arrive the repos in 2-3 weeks, so that will probably bring the fix.
I questioned for workarounds because some of you thought that fixing it would require an ABI break. Fortunately it didn't :)